# Basedir's parent directory - NLog configuration

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I'm using NLog in a multi-project solution. I set the `filename` property of the config file to `"${basedir}/logs/logFile.log"` and the problem is: the logs directory is being created in each project's main directory, so each project has its own set of logs. What I'd like to have is a single log directory for the whole solution, so basically it means setting the `filename` to basedir's parent directory.
How exactly can I do it? `"../${basedir}/logs/logFile.log"` doesn't seem to work, the logs are still saved to the same directory.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar situation. I needed the /logs/ directory to be a sibling of the actual directory of my project. I found that this works for me with:

```
fileName="${basedir}/../logs/logFile.log"
```

I'm using NLog 2.1.0

Comment: This makes no difference, at least, not in the latest (4) version of NLog.

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example the `${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}/logs/logFile.log` This will create the log in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\logs`

This solution will also work on an enterprise application, because this folder has all the user rights necessary in order for the application process to write the logs.

Comment: It's a web app though, so when it gets deployed onto IIS I'd like the logs to be saved in the application's main directory, not somewhere in the sever administrator's profile folder :)

Comment: Even for a web application, the user which runs the application should not have write permissions in the folder of the application. Why don't you create a special folder in another place? And in the configuration file, specify the real path to this folder. Example: `D:\Data\MyApplication\Logs`

Comment: To echo @CristinaAlboni point: log files should *never* go in the app directory, this opens up potential security issues.  They should go in a separate logs folder, ideally on a different drive (and never System (C:)) so that there's no chance excessive log files could bring down the server.